# How can I convert an RSS feed to Atom, inline?

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I admit to being a bit behind the times when it comes to understanding RSS/Atom feed issues.

All I know is, I want to have an Atom feed converted to an RSS feed inline.  Meaning that I want to specify an option somewhere that says use this xsl or whatever to convert the Atom feed to an RSS feed.

Is there some way to accomplish this that doesn't require running a separate listener on my local box to do the translation? I.e. Instead of directly asking for the Atom feed, I get my 'service' to get the feed, transform it and give it to the real subscriber?

Sorry for the (probably) dumb question.  Somehow I never got the memo on this stuff.

Thanks - Jon

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Paul's answer...  we use [Feedburner](http://www.feedburner.com) for feeds - it's trivial to have it convert one type of feed to another.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  What if the feed is behind the firewall with my consuming applications?

Comment: Jon -
In that case, there are a couple of ways you can do it.
1. Transform the RSS XML to Atom, via XSLT (http://atom.geekhood.net/)
2. Use a class to do this:  (http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/xml/Atom_To_Rss_Feed_Convertor.aspx)

Comment: Jon - that first link for the XSLT solution seems to only have Atom to RSS, and I can't find any prewritten RSS2Atom XSLT, so try the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Atom to RSS on the fly

Sounds like a Yahoo Pipes job to me..

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=Aj_YHfi62xGuBj4KkAtvUw

Comment: Thanks Paul.  What if the feed is behind the firewall with my consuming applications?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own, using C#. You would download the Atom and save it as RSS using the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class. It's about 4 lines of code.